# Flutter wrap textview right overflow error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem about wrap text overflow right.
I know that I should use flexible but where?
This is my flutter code. I want to solve right overflow error.

```
      class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
     const PhotosList({Key? key, required this.photos}) : super(key: key);

       final List<Photo> photos;

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(child: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {


    //UI for dekstop
    if (constraints.maxWidth > 1200) {
      return ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: photos.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey,
            spreadRadius: 0.0,
            blurRadius: 1.0,
            offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0))
                ]),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(
          children: [
              Container(child: Image.network(photos[index].activityPhoto,
              width: 200,
              height: 100,),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20,),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                Text(photos[index].activityDate),
                Text(photos[index].activityName),
                Text(photos[index].activityDetails),
              ],),
          ],
        )),
      );
    });
```

Target of this code show a list with a design. 1 image and 3 texts.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Column of Text which is throwing overflow error with Flexible widget:

Code:

```
Flexible(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("photos[index].activityDate"),
                        Text("photos[index].activityName"),
                        Text("photos[index].activityDetails"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```